# API endpoint URL with <id> or without?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

What approach is recommended? API endpoint URL with  or without?

`/api/orders/<id>/`

```
def post(self, request, id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=self.kwargs.get('id'), company=request.user.company)
    ...
```

or `/api/orders/`

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
             order_id = serializer.validated_data.get('order_id')
             order = Order.objects.get(pk=order_id)
             if order.user.company != request.user.company:
                 raise Http404
              ....
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

If you're attempting to retrieve results (i.e. HTTP GET), then you could use "/api/orders" to retrieve all orders, and "/api/orders/{id}" to retrieve a specific order.

On the other hand, if you're trying to create a new order (i.e. HTTP POST), then "/api/orders/" can be used to create a new order, and upon successful creation, the response body will return the order object (including a unique ID).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we can use [ListCreateAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) class of DRF to `List` [GET] all the objects and `Create` [POST] a new object instance at some end-point like `api/v1/orders/`.

And to fetch/update/delete [GET/PATCH/DELETE] any single instance we can use [RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdatedestroyapiview) class of DRF hooked at some end-points of form `api/v1/orders/<pk>/`

Generally speaking end-points like `api/v1/orders/` should `list` all available/applicable objects and appending `<pk>` to it should return `details` of object associated with that pk, otherwise handled properly with `404` or some other relevant status code.

My manager always used to refer me to this, so I would like to pass on the same; Do checkout https://developer.github.com/v3/

Reference :

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdatedestroyapiview